# How to properly code a set of walking and idle animations for a top-down isometric character for actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, isometric

I have a character for a top-down isometric game. The character is to move in eight directions, so eight idle and eight walking animations. I have the walking animations working [except for diagonal walking animations, I get a still frame for those] but if I try to add the idle animation, my walking animations get borked completely.

I'm trying to get the character to go into the idle animation based on what direction they were facing [like if they're going left, the idle will be left, if they're going diagonally up and right, then the idle will be up and right, etc.] but if I try any sort of idle code, the walk animations do not play and the idle will always be in only one direction.

Here's what I managed to get working so far:

```
    private var speed = Number;
    private var kLeft:Boolean = false;      
    private var kRight:Boolean = false;     
    private var kUp:Boolean = false;        
    private var kDown:Boolean = false;

    //[misc code and listeners]

    private function onFrame(e:Event)
    {
        if (kLeft == true){
            this.x -= 2*speed;
            this.gotoAndStop("WalkSide");
            this.scaleX = -1;}
        if (kRight == true){
            this.x += 2*speed;
            this.gotoAndStop("WalkSide");
            this.scaleX = 1;}
        if (kUp == true){
            this.y -= 1.5*speed;
            this.gotoAndStop("WalkUp");}
        if (kDown == true){
            this.y += 1.5*speed;
            this.gotoAndStop("WalkDown");}

        if (kUp == true && kLeft == true){
            this.gotoAndStop("WalkUpdiagonal");
            this.scaleX = -1;}
        if (kUp == true && kRight == true){
            this.gotoAndStop("WalkUpdiagonal");
            this.scaleX = 1;}
        if (kDown == true && kLeft == true){
            this.gotoAndStop("WalkDowndiagonal");
            this.scaleX = -1;}
        if (kDown == true && kRight == true){
            this.gotoAndStop("WalkDowndiagonal");
            this.scaleX = 1;}
    }//onFrame

    private function keyPressed(k:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if (k.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
            kLeft = true;
        if (k.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
            kRight = true;
        if (k.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
            kUp = true;
        if (k.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
            kDown = true;           
    }//keypressed

    private function keyReleased(k:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if (k.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
            kLeft = false;
        if (k.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
            kRight = false;
        if (k.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
            kUp = false;
        if (k.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
            kDown = false;
    }//keyreleased
```

So how do I add in coding that if I release [kLeft] then "IdleSide" is visible, etc?

[Here is my current .swf file.](http://puu.sh/ga5uO.swf)

Answer (score 0):

Given your current code, one way you can try would be to separate out your direction handling and walking/idle states.

**Right now, it looks like you're doing this:**
You set a boolean upon key press and on enter frame you check if that boolean is true, then you walk in that direction.

**Instead, you can do this:**
Have a set of direction states (booleans in your case) and character states (two booleans for now, one for walking, one for idle)

Upon key press, you set both the direction state and character state (say, from idle to walking + left).
Upon key release, you only update the character state and leave the direction state alone (from walking to idle).
Then, in your enter frame loop, you can look up both the direction and character state as to which animation to play, which would be idle + left.

In the future, you may run in to an issue of having tons of flags/booleans if you decide to implement more character states (say.. "resting", or "running"). It might be worth it at this point to do some research in to other ways to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to rewrite your code in a more legible and organized way. The best way to achieve this is something like this:

first of all, creat a movie clip container for each direction's animation, in this example I will only use 4 directions, so we would have:

- leftAnimations_mc
- rightAnimations_mc
- upAnimations_mc
- downAnimations_mc

on each frame separate each animation in one of this ways:

1.- each animation in diferent layers, one animation after another, labeling each animation's start keyframe such as "idle", "walk", "run" and so on.

2.- each animation inside a movie clip ("leftIdle_mc", "leftWalk_mc", etc) and add each animation in a different keyframe in your main animations movie clip: "leftAnimations_mc", and label each frame the same way as the previous eample: "idle, walk, run". (I prefer this way because in case you need to update your animation (making it longer or shorter) its easier just tu update the frame in your inner leftIdle_mc or leftWalk_mc, and having the main leftAnimations_mc (which holds all the other animations) intact.

3.- create a new MovieClip called player_mc, and add each animation container in different layers of this movieClip and set an instance name for each animation movieclip.

in the end you should have something like this:

```
player_mc -> leftAnimation_mc -> "idle" keyframe -> leftIdle_mc
                              -> "walk" keyframe -> leftWalk_mc
          -> rightAnimation_mc-> "idle" keyframe -> rightIdle_mc
```

(you got the idea...)

now for the coding:
1.- setup your directions and animations like constants, declare a variable for the current direction and declare a variable for the current animation:

```
private const LEFT:string = "left";
private const RIGHT:string = "right";
private const UP:string = "up";
private const DOWN:string = "down";

private const IDLE:string = "idle";
private const WALK:string = "walk";

private var currentDirection:string = "right";
private var animation:string = "idle";
```

2.- add your keyDown and keyUp listeners.
in your keyDown event listener, instead of setting true or false values, set your current direction depending on the key pressed, add the animation you want to call and finally add a new method called updateAnimations() e.g.:

```
if(k.KeyCode == KeyBoardLeft)
{
    currentDirection = LEFT;
    animation = WALK;
    updateAnimations();
}
```

3.- on your key up/released event, just change your animation to IDLE and also add the updateAnimations method:

```
private function keyReleased(k:KeyboardEvent)
{
    animation = IDLE;
    updateAnimations();
}
```

4.- finally the updateAnimations and hideAnimations methods:

```
private updateAnimations()
{
    hideAnimations();

    switch(currentDirection)
    {
         case LEFT:
         player_mc.leftAnimations_mc.visible = true; 
         player_mc.leftAnimations_mc.gotoAndStop(animation);
         break;

         case RIGHT: 
         player_mc.rightAnimations_mc.visible = true; 
         player_mc.rightAnimations_mc.gotoAndStop(animation);
         break;
    }
}

private hideAnimations()
{
    player_mc.leftAnimations_mc.visible = false;
    player_mc.rightAnimations_mc.visible = false;
    player_mc.upAnimations_mc.visible = false;
    player_mc.downAnimations_mc.visible = false;
}
```

as you can see, I've used hideAnimations() to hide all the animations movie clips, and then with a switch I set visible only the animation I want, finally I just goto the current animation key frame:

```
player_mc.rightAnimations_mc.gotoAndStop(animation);
```

Hope this is clear enough.